# How to create inherit from std::allocator and is it resonable?

Tags: c++, windows, stl, memory-management, allocator

What I wonder about is simple - if we create a DLL, compile it with static runtime, while in its code we will create a simple allocator that inherits from std::allocator, would it be possible for us to Having N difrent heaps use only this library heap (one with allocator) for memory management across all N heaps? And how to create such allocator?

Comment: You are aware that standard allocators are *stateless*, right?

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, it *is* possible to create private heaps.  Check out the [heap functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366711.aspx) on MSDN.  However, the C++ standard library allocators have a *stateless* interface.  Thus, two allocators of the same type have to be interchangeable (memory allocated by one can be released by the other).

So, yes you can achieve this, but not with `std::allocator`.